# Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, reflect-metadata

While trying to run my Angular2 app with typescript and npm I am getting the error in title. As said in similar topics I tried the "import 'reflect-metadata'; "
But it didn't work.

This is the dependency in my package.json file:

```
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
```

Thanks in advance for your time

P.S:This happened after I upgraded my app from rc4 to rc5

**Edit 1**

More details about error:

```
checkReflect    @   vendor.js:40700
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:40702
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:40791
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:30176
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:30215
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:30634
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:30652
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:37326
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:37842
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:36288
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:37305
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:26058
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:26118
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:9935
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:10294
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12761
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12871
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12255
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12657
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12907
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12935
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12885
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:12892
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:6709
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:6746
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:148
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:49327
(anonymous function)    @   vendor.js:49528
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
expanded    @   vendor.js:34
(anonymous function)    @   main.js:404
initModule  @   vendor.js:43
require @   vendor.js:60
(anonymous function)    @   (index):38
```

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce it ?

Comment: @candidJ This is git link: https://github.com/Miss-Git/R-Panel

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same issue and I too upgraded from rc4 to rc5 (using webpack here)

Comment: @Manatax not yet. but i figured out the problem is with 'Reflect.getMetadata'. I'll update this post if there are any developments

Comment: I switched from webpack to systemjs until this gets solved :P

Comment: Any progress with this?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem with `angular 4.1.3` with `cli` build when I upgraded my swagger generated client code for rest end points (swagger editor 2.2.3).

I have added `reflect-metadata` and its worked for me. Any one facing the issue after `angular 4` and have `cli` may help this.

The error message was little different as below

```
_fails.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/_descriptors.js (_descriptors.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aaad282eb132f1a48d07:54)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js (es6.symbol.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aaad282eb132f1a48d07:54)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/es6/symbol.js (polyfills.bundle.js:1560)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aaad282eb132f1a48d07:54)
    at Object../src/polyfills.ts (ckset.ts:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aaad282eb132f1a48d07:54)
    at Object.2 (polyfills.bundle.js:13849)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aaad282eb132f1a48d07:54)
core.es5.js:354 Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
```

Comment: where have you added it?

Comment: add it in your package.json file which will install the reflection-metadata in your project dependencires.

Answer (score 1):

There should be errors in console that explain why `reflect-metadata` wasn't loaded.

The existing problem with 0.1.3 is that it has [conditional dependencies](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators/blob/v0.1.3/Reflect.js#L839-L840) that can be erroneously included by modular systems (SystemJS, Webpack, etc). This doesn't happen if the script is loaded in normal fashion,

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
```

Later package version should be used to use `reflect-metadata` with modular systems, 0.1.8 is available at this moment.

Comment: I added details of error. Please check it and help me solve it with your kind suggestions

Comment: It concerns your build rather than anything else. You don't `require('vendor')` module. It is the one that applies polyfills and everything.